# PDF not opening / downloading in Microsoft EDGE

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, microsoft-edge

I have a few PDFs in an S3 bucket and downloading / opening behaves differently in browsers.

In Firefox, PDF loads and opens instantly. 
In EDGE PDF doesnt open at all. The loading page icon appears but nothing happens.

I have tried opening a PDF from a random website and then it loads perfectly fine in EDGE.. Then my guess is a different header setup at S3 that is not aknowledged by EDGE.

HTML is the same, just `a` tag and link. The PDF has been uploaded with PAPERCLIP and access method is `private` (a temporary URL is created). (But again no problem in Firefox...)

(There are threads about EDGE not opening PDFs at all, but in my case, it does open PDFs from other websites ..)

Comment: can you share a link to the pdf? Even in private? I work at Microsoft on Edge and would love to get it to the team to diagnose why it is broken.

Comment: sure here is the link (will be up for 100 000 seconds then expired message error from S3) https://skeypesdev.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/diagnostiqueurreponses/diagnostics/000/000/002/original/PDF_file.pdf?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAJOWMAUYC3D5JUVOA%2F20170808%2Feu-west-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20170808T091322Z&X-Amz-Expires=100000&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Signature=d2ac0177e7c8ece1e26074dec22d90aa9b3076d061c9fb91538ade07b3b16b18

Comment: if useful, I have allowed users to download instead of opening by changing the header to "disposition: attachment" and it downloads fine. But in this case the file is downloaded by Heroku from S3 first and then streamed to my user as attachment

Comment: to be clear - this file is not opening in edge for you? its opening fine for me at the moment

Comment: no it's not opening on my side in EDGE. I see loading icon in the tab but not opening when clicking the above link. May just be my EDGE setup but oddly, some PDF from other sites do open. So i guess it is a problem with direct download from S3

Comment: my Edge version is : Microsoft Edge 40.15063.0.0 Microsoft EdgeHTML 15.15063. If you sandbox this version you should be able to replicate it I guess

Comment: I did, and I still can not replicate - https://git.io/v7ikQ

Comment: Humm Strange. I am running Windows 10 on a new DELL XPS 15 laptop. Maybe Something on my own configuration prevent the PDF to open. (but EDGE opens PDFs on random websites still..) And I don't have any adblocker or such. My internet provider may also block but why only from AWS S3 and if used with EDGE...